# How to display a Funnel Chart with Grand Total values?

Tags: reporting, customization

I am working on creating some Funnel reports, for Non funneled objects.

I am working based on the idea posted by [Luke Duncan](http://fullcirclecrm.com/how-to-track-key-funnel-metrics-within-salesforce-part-1/)

I have the summary of the fields/stages that I want, and I want to display them as a funnel report.

[image]

so it will look like:

[image]

The row's width will display the "power" of the number, so top row should be 100% wide, and will display value of: 843

2nd row, will be 783/843 wide, and display 783 as value, etc...

Using the built in Funnel, I can't use the Totals as the Segments (which is what I think I need)

Even the simplest funnel report/chart (all opptys, grouped by stage) only shows a current snapshot of the funnel, and not a historical/step by step of what happened)

[image: Only current stage is shown, while I want to see cumulative numbering]

ideas?